# Openstack Compute fails to run instances based on flavor and number of instances

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, centos8

I am attempting to create various instances and Compute is failing to spawn some of them.

My instance has the following characteristics:

Name: ThirdInstance
Created from image: CentOS-7-x86_64
Flavor: m1.medium (2 VCPU, 4GB RAM, 40GB Disk)

I have two other instances running. I was unable to spawn these instances unless I used the flavor m1.small (1VCPU, 2GB RAM, 20GB Disk). Any deviation from that flavor and the instance spawning failed.

Unfortunately, my ThirdInstance fails to spawn regardless of the flavor used. I have tried creating it with m1.small and it fails consistently.

I looked at the Nova logs, and am noting that when I attempt to create this instance I am consistently getting the following message in the nova-conductor.log file:

```
2020-08-29 13:21:09.637 98391 ERROR nova.conductor.manager
2020-08-29 13:21:09.637 98391 ERROR nova.conductor.manager
2020-08-29 13:21:09.890 98391 WARNING nova.scheduler.utils [req-30539015-22f1-4d46-b8b7-63f9c679eed1 4c4c7de6dd134250972958ce260530f2 166dc91ccec24f21963c71a437380ee9 - default default] Failed to compute_task_build_instances: No valid host was found.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 241, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/scheduler/manager.py", line 200, in select_destinations
    raise exception.NoValidHost(reason="")

nova.exception.NoValidHost: No valid host was found.
: nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found.
2020-08-29 13:21:09.891 98391 WARNING nova.scheduler.utils [req-30539015-22f1-4d46-b8b7-63f9c679eed1 4c4c7de6dd134250972958ce260530f2 166dc91ccec24f21963c71a437380ee9 - default default] [instance: fe54feaf-ecb6-4725-97e9-7d208066ddb0] Setting instance to ERROR state.: nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found.
```

What am I missing here? What causes these No Host Found failures when I attempt to use flavors other than m1.small, and why does a third instance fail to spawn regardless of the flavor used??? How (if possible) can I get these instances to run properly?

NOTE: I am using an installation created from Packstack on CentOS 8. My machine is a 2- core with 32G of RAM and 3 Terabytes of disk space. The Openstack version is Ussuri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you have not enough resources, especially CPU-cores. You have written, that your node has only two cores and you had already spawned 2 VMs with small flavor, which requires 1 core each. This `No valid host was found`-error comes also, when no compute-host was found with enough resources for the selected flavor.

You can check this by yourself:

Run `openstack hypervisor list` to list your hypervisor and then `openstack hypervisor show <ID>` with the id of your hypervisor. In the output you find `vcpus` and `vcpus_used`. `vcpus` is the maximum available number of cpu-cores on the selected compute-host. Based on the information of your question, I think both of these values are `2` in your case and that would show you, that you have not enough resources for your third VM.

Comment: So it sounds like the number of instances you can spawn depends on the number of cores your hardware has. Question: is it possible to stop one or more running instances so that you can run another one? I am still a newbie in some of these matters...

Comment: It depends on your available resources in general (cpu, ram, disk). Beside this the flavor of your VMs also matter. The bigger the flavors, the less the available number of VMs. For cores it is also possible to use overprovisioning, but I never used this by myself. With this it should be also possible to run more on the same amount of cores. The only way to free the allocated cores and ram of the VM, without deleting a VM. is `openstack shelve`-command, as far as I know. Only the data on the disc and the meta-data in the openstack-database remain and the hypervisor is free again.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Tobias. I have upgraded my machine so that it has a CPU with 8 cores in it. I have the CPU power now, but it turns out what is stopping me from doing things is the disk space. While I have 3 Terabytes my root partition is too small. This is a different problem that will require a different question.

Comment: how do you set it so it can use host resources?

Comment: @shorif2000 what kind of host resources do you mean? the local disc on the compute-hosts?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to increase the compute node physical resources so it can be allocated when creating instances off images on openstack